# Is postal address suitable for sort key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

[DynamoDB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdM1n.png)

I was planning to remove the restaurantId (primary key) attribute, and make  the restaurantName (partition key) and the restaurantAddress (sort key) a composite primary key. This is partly because the restaurantId has no business value here and it makes putting new items troublesome.

My question here is that if using a postal address as sort key is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general question with a DB key is whether it's unique and stable. Both are dubious. A food court in a building may have multiple restaurants share a single address, and a restaurant may switch to a PO box which changes their postal address.